# Using Fresco with StaggeredGridLayoutManager

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-cardview, fresco

I followed [this](http://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/) decent tutorial and everything was going great with the local images.  When trying to change from the local images to the ones which I load through Fresco into SimpleDraweeView I can't seem to get the view to resize and stagger itself amongst the other images.

My layout looks like this (it is :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:card_view="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:fresco="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/card_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    card_view:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
    card_view:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
            android:id="@+id/fresco_image"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            fresco:actualImageScaleType="fitXY"
            />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="13sp"
            android:text="@string/hello_world"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:layout_below="@+id/fresco_image"
            android:paddingBottom="8dp"
            android:paddingTop="8dp"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:background="#1976D2"/>
    </RelativeLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

The above is inflated into the following:

```
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/view"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/text"
        android:scrollbars="vertical">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

On my drawee I've tried:

1. Setting width or height or both to "match_parent" and "wrap_content" with all variations.  The wrap_content setting doesn't seem [recommended](http://frescolib.org/docs/using-drawees-xml.html)
2. Different aspect rations, but that seems to result in images cropped and all a uniform size/shape (not staggered)
3. Different combinations of scaleType with the above.

Outside of the drawee I've been looking at some of the demos from [GitHub](https://github.com/facebook/fresco), but I can't seem to locate any examples of a staggered view.

I'm sure it's just a matter of getting the settings in the right combination, but for the like of me I can't figure out what that combination happens to be.

Any suggestions (or samples) would be appreciated!!

**UPDATE**
Our backend implementation returns the aspect ratio (as well as the width/height) for each picture.  I was able to set the aspect ratio on the SimpleDraweeView and it respected those values:

```
vDraweeView.setAspectRatio(fAspect);
```

It'd be cooler if I didn't have to do this, but apparently the view doesn't know it's size until the image is fully loaded.  While this might be a good time to resize the view, this could lead to a jumpy display...not desirable!!

Does this sound right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the SimpleDraweeView doesn't know the size of the image until it's downloaded (and resizing after it's initially drawn isn't recommended for shifting UI reasons -- maybe other reasons), I had to set the aspect ratio prior to downloading the image.  This assumes you know the aspect ratio prior to downloading the image...which we do in our case.  I did this in the recyclerview adapter.

Command to set the aspect ratio:

```
vDraweeView.setAspectRatio(fAspect);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this alternative WrapContentDraweeView class:

```
public class WrapContentDraweeView extends GenericDraweeView {

private PipelineDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier mDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier;
private PipelineDraweeControllerBuilder mSimpleDraweeControllerBuilder;


public WrapContentDraweeView(Context context, GenericDraweeHierarchy hierarchy) {
    super(context, hierarchy);
    this.init(context, (AttributeSet) null);
}

public WrapContentDraweeView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.init(context, (AttributeSet) null);
}

public WrapContentDraweeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.init(context, attrs);
}

public WrapContentDraweeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.init(context, attrs);
}

@TargetApi(21)
public WrapContentDraweeView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr,
                             int defStyleRes) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr, defStyleRes);
    this.init(context, attrs);
}

private void init(Context context, @Nullable AttributeSet attrs) {

    if (!this.isInEditMode()) {
        mDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier = Fresco.getDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier();
        Preconditions.checkNotNull(mDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier,
                "SimpleDraweeView was not initialized!");
        this.mSimpleDraweeControllerBuilder = mDraweeControllerBuilderSupplier.get();
        if (attrs != null) {
            TypedArray gdhAttrs = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs,
                    R.styleable.SimpleDraweeView);

            try {
                if (gdhAttrs.hasValue(
                        R.styleable.SimpleDraweeView_actualImageUri)) {
                    this.setImageURI((Uri) Uri.parse(gdhAttrs.getString(
                            R.styleable.SimpleDraweeView_actualImageUri)),
                            (Object) null);
                } else if (gdhAttrs.hasValue(
                        R.styleable.SimpleDraweeView_actualImageResource)) {
                    int resId = gdhAttrs.getResourceId(
                            R.styleable.SimpleDraweeView_actualImageResource,
                            -1);

                }
            } finally {
                gdhAttrs.recycle();
            }
        }

    }
}

protected SimpleDraweeControllerBuilder getControllerBuilder() {
    return this.mSimpleDraweeControllerBuilder;
}

public void setImageURI(Uri uri) {
    this.setImageURI((Uri) uri, (Object) null);
}

public void setImageURI(@Nullable String uriString) {
    this.setImageURI((String) uriString, (Object) null);
}

public void setImageURI(Uri uri, @Nullable Object callerContext) {
    setAspectRatio(FrescoUtils.getAspectRatio(uri));
    ImageDecodeOptions decoderOptions = ImageDecodeOptions.newBuilder()
            .setDecodePreviewFrame(true)

            .build();
    ImageRequest imageRequest = ImageRequestBuilder.newBuilderWithSource(uri)

            .setLocalThumbnailPreviewsEnabled(true)
            .setImageDecodeOptions(decoderOptions)

            .setPostprocessor(new BasePostprocessor() {
                @Override
                public CloseableReference<Bitmap> process(Bitmap sourceBitmap,
                                                          PlatformBitmapFactory bitmapFactory) {
                    int height = sourceBitmap.getHeight()/2;
                    int width = sourceBitmap.getWidth()/2;
                    if (width / (float) height < 0.5f) {
                        CloseableReference<Bitmap> cropReference = null;
                        CloseableReference<Bitmap> scaledReference = null;
                        try {
                            cropReference = bitmapFactory
                                    .createBitmap(sourceBitmap, 0, 0, width,
                                            (int) (width / 1.66f));
                            scaledReference = bitmapFactory
                                    .createScaledBitmap(cropReference.get(), getWidth(),
                                            (int) (getWidth() / 1.66f), false);
                            Bitmap bm = scaledReference.get();
                            Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bm);
                            Bitmap badge = getBadgeBitmap("长图");
                            int padding = (int) (getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density
                                    * 16);
                            canvas.drawBitmap(badge, bm.getWidth() - badge.getWidth() - padding,
                                    bm.getHeight() - badge.getHeight() - padding, new Paint());
                            return super.process(bm, bitmapFactory);
                        } finally {
                            if (cropReference != null) {
                                cropReference.close();
                            }
                            if (scaledReference != null) {
                                scaledReference.close();
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    return super.process(sourceBitmap, bitmapFactory);
                }
            })

            .build();

    DraweeController controller = this.mSimpleDraweeControllerBuilder
            .setImageRequest(imageRequest)
            .setCallerContext(callerContext)
            .setOldController(this.getController())
            .setAutoPlayAnimations(true)
            .setControllerListener(FrescoUtils.createControllerListener(this, uri))
            .setOldController(this.getController())


            .build();
    this.setController(controller);
}

public void setImageURI(@Nullable String uriString, @Nullable Object callerContext) {
    Uri uri = uriString != null ? Uri.parse(uriString) : null;
    this.setImageURI(uri, callerContext);
}



public void setImageResource(int resId) {
    super.setImageResource(resId);
}


private Bitmap getBadgeBitmap(String badge) {

    final DisplayMetrics dm = getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    final float density = dm.density;
    final float scaledDensity = dm.scaledDensity;
    final TextPaint textPaint = new TextPaint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG | Paint
            .SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG);
    textPaint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    textPaint.setTypeface(Typeface.create("sans-serif-black", Typeface.NORMAL));
    textPaint.setTextSize(12 * scaledDensity);

    final float padding = 4 * density;
    final float cornerRadius = 2 * density;
    final Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    textPaint.getTextBounds(badge, 0, badge.length(), textBounds);
    final int height = (int) (padding + textBounds.height() + padding);
    final int width = (int) (padding + textBounds.width() + padding);
    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    bitmap.setHasAlpha(true);
    final Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    final Paint backgroundPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);

    backgroundPaint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    RectF rectF = new RectF(0, 0, width, height);
    canvas.drawRoundRect(rectF, cornerRadius, cornerRadius, backgroundPaint);
    // punch out the badge word, leaving transparency
  //        textPaint.setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));

    // 居中
    Paint.FontMetrics fontMetrics = textPaint.getFontMetrics();
    int baseline = (int) (rectF.centerY() - (fontMetrics.top + fontMetrics.bottom) / 2);
    textPaint.setTextAlign(Paint.Align.CENTER);
    canvas.drawText(badge, rectF.centerX(), baseline, textPaint);
    return bitmap;
}
}
```

and then in your layout use WrapContentDraweeView instead of SimpleDraweeView
and use your package name instead of fresco package

```
<com.package.info.WrapContentDraweeView

       android:id="@+id/gridThumbnail"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"


    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/placeholder"
    />
```

this is better than backend implementation.

Answer (score 0):

I had an similar problem, but i was using Glide. Anyway, try to set your ImageView using this properties below. My StaggeredGridView has 2 columns and worked great.

```
   <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
        android:hardwareAccelerated="true"
        app:cardPreventCornerOverlap="false"
        android:elevation="0dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/item_cover"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Other thing i had to make to solve bugs when loading images, was use an PlaceHolder until image is loaded.

```
           Glide.with(context)
                .load(url)
                .placeholder(R.drawable.transparent_placeholder)
                .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
                .crossFade()
                .into(itemCover)
```